# SQLite database fails when create

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this database create method:

```
private void addDataBase() throws SQLException {

        File FestivaleDir = new File("/sdcard/Ementor/");
        if (!FestivaleDir.exists()) {
            FestivaleDir.mkdirs();

        }   

        emBase.db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase(
                "/storage/emulated/0/Ementor/EyeModbusAndroid.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    }
```

and if I run it on Android 4.2 or higher it works good, but below it fails and the logcat says:

> 12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error
>   (code 14): Could not open database 12-05 15:15:08.414:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:827)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:816)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:215)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   com.eyecom.modbusandroid.Main.addDataBase(Main.java:138) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   com.eyecom.modbusandroid.Main.onCreateView(Main.java:120) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323) 12-05 15:15:08.414:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323) 12-05 15:15:08.414:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:579) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323) 12-05 15:15:08.414:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2155)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323) 12-05 15:15:08.414:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1854) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4218)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-05 15:15:08.414:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-05 15:15:08.414:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   12-05 15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 12-05
>   15:15:08.414: E/AndroidRuntime(19945):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't attempt to specify a full path to the database like `"/storage/emulated/0/Ementor/EyeModbusAndroid.db"`. Just the filename part is enough i.e. `"EyeModbusAndroid.db"`.

The platform will make sure the database is placed in an appropriate folder for your app.

However, you *can* specify a full path if you *really* want to. Just make sure that

- the path begins with `File.separatorChar` i.e. `/`
- the path is valid (the last directory component does not need to exist, it is created if needed)
- the path is readable and writable i.e. you have the necessary permissions

Comment: then how can i put make the db in the Ementro directory?